# Python: Am I using "self" correctly?

Tags: python, syntax, self

I'm new to Python and am only now starting to see the uses of `self` and would like to know if I am using it correctly. I have some sample code below and was wondering if someone could just skim through and see if it's the correct usage. I'm not sure if it's correct because I seem to be needing to use `self` a lot but perhaps that is just the style of the language. Thank You

**Code**

```
from tkinter import Canvas

class BouncyBall:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.d = 15
        self.color = 'blue'
        self.speed = 2
        self.move_left = False
        self.move_right = False

    def __init__(self, x, y, d, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.d = d
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 2
        self.move_left = False
        self.move_right = False

    #Accessor Methods
    def get_x(self):
        return self.x
    def get_y(self):
        return self.y
    def get_diameter(self):
        return self.d
    def get_color(self):
        return self.color
    def get_speed(self):
        return self.speed
    def moving_right(self):
        return self.move_right
    def moving_left(self):
        return self.move_left

    #Mutator Methods
    def set_x(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def set_y(self, y):
        self.y = y
    def set_diameter(self, d):
        self.d = d
    def set_color(self, color):
        self.color = color
    def set_speed(self, speed):
        self.speed = speed
    def set_move_right(self, move_right):
        self.move_right = move_right
    def set_move_left(self, move_left):
        self.move_left = move_left

    def draw_ball(self, canvas):
        if isinstance(canvas, Canvas):
            canvas.create_oval(self.x, self.y, self.x + self.d, self.y + self.d, fill=self.color)
        else:
            print("Improper Parameter Sent In")
```

Comment: You shouldn't be writing getters and setters in Python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga How else would I get/change the values? Or are the `self` variables public?

Comment: I believe they're always public.

Comment: There are no access modifiers in Python, i.e. there is no "public" and "private". Everything is accessible directly.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ok, I was unsure about that. Thank you for the help

Comment: Technically, an instance attribute that begins with double underscores (and doesn't end with underscores) is "private", in that automatic name mangling occurs so you don't accidentally use it outside the class's methods. It's trivial to bypass that mangling (by doing it yourself), so it's not a security feature, it's just a convenient way to namespace privates so a subclass can't accidentally stomp on them.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Hm, on one hand, I feel that name-mangling and access modifiers are not really the same thing. In this case, it is the same effect but they serve different purposes. Or perhaps, name-mangling serves a much more constrained purpose than a private access modifier? Not sure how I feel about it now.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Well, given that `private` is *never* a real security feature (introspective or pointer manipulation abilities of most languages that offer it mean you can read the "private" attributes if you're sufficiently determined/insane), I consider name mangling to be "private, but we make sure it's obvious that the purpose is code design related, not security". The name mangling really does serve the same purpose, to allow a class to declare an attribute/method that won't conflict with an attribute of the same name in a super or subclass and outsiders can't access by accident.

Comment: Basically, both of them are about interface design, and that's it. Access modifiers just happen to make people believe (erroneously) that they do more than that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `self` correctly.  It does tend to appear a lot in Python compared with other languages like C++ where the `this` parameter is implicit.

However, in Python it is not conventional to write `get()` and `set()` methods for everything, as you have done.  You can reduce your code quite a bit by removing those--and remove a lot of `self`s in the process.

Answer (score 4):

Well, first off your `__init__` is wrong. Python doesn't allow two definitions of a function/method with the same name in the same namespace, whether or not the prototype differs. I'd suggest dropping your first definition, and changing the `def` line of the second to:

```
def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, d=15, color='blue'):
```

which will do what you wanted (allow you to initialize without arguments by using default values).

You also probably want to drop all your `set_` and `get_` methods. If the attributes are read/write, just access them normally without getters and setters. If at some later point you need to make them read-only, or compute them, you can rename the attribute to have a leading underscore (e.g. `_x`) and use `@property` decorators to continue providing attribute-like access (with or without writability). That would instantly remove the vast majority of (unnecessary) accessor and mutator methods that make you reference `self` so often. For example, if `x` should be read-only, you'd set `self._x = x` in your `__init__`, then define a property:

```
@property
def x(self):
    return self._x
```

and users would continue to read it as if it were a simple attribute, they just couldn't write it by accident (they could directly write `_x`, but that's their problem; Python's philosophy is that we're all adults, and if you ignore the convention that underscore prefixes are internal implementation details, the consequences are on your head).

Otherwise, yes, you'll be referencing `self` a lot. Python prefers explicit namespacing to implicit, so you use `self` to differentiate between instance access and scoped variable access. If you are going to be using a given variable a lot (and it won't change during the course of a method), you can cache it to a local name and use the local name unqualified, e.g.:

```
 def some_method(self):
     # We use x a lot and never change it, so cache up front:
     x = self.x

     # Can read cached x over and over without qualification for rest of method
```